# problem with bullets shooting in FPS game

Tags: 3d, javascript, first-person-shooter

Please check out my game here: http://still-escarpment-3701.herokuapp.com

The problem is with shooting. The bullets keep on moving with the First person controller instead of moving from the same position and direction from which they were shot.

```
///////////////////code for shooting from fps///////////////////////////////////
         ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // the bullet to be thrown and shoot ......

        bulletTemplate = new J3D.Transform();
        bulletTemplate.geometry = J3D.Primitive.Sphere(0.5, 4, 4);
        bulletTemplate.renderer = J3D.BuiltinShaders.fetch("Normal2Color");


        // bullet holder bullets ko apni gun main rakhe ga ....
        bulletHolder = new J3D.Transform();


         engine.scene.add(bulletHolder);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;

        document.onmouseup = function(e) {
        var b = bulletTemplate.clone();

            var fz = first_person_controller.forward();
            b.direction = new v3();
            b.direction.fromArray(fz);

            b.position.fromArray(fz).mult(3);
            b.progress = 0;
            b.ttl = 300;

            b.animate = function() {
                b.position = b.direction.cp().mult(3 + b.progress);
                b.progress += 1;
                b.ttl--;



                if(b.ttl == 0) {
                    bulletHolder.remove(b);
                }
            }

            bulletHolder.add(b);

        };
```

The code below is being called in the game loop function's `draw()`.

```
bulletHolder.position.x =first_person_controller.position.x;
bulletHolder.position.y =first_person_controller.position.y;
bulletHolder.position.z =first_person_controller.position.z;

first_person_controller.rotation.y = mx;

for(var i = 0; i < bulletHolder.numChildren; i++) {
    bulletHolder.childAt(i).animate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are using [J3D.js](http://everyday3d.com/j3d/apidocs/).*

Add your bullets to the `bulletHolder` at the position of the `first_person_controller`.

```
// Instead of:
b.position.fromArray(fz).mult(3);
// Do:
b.position.fromArray(first_person_controller.position);
// Or, if you want the bullet to start a few units in front of the player:
b.position = v3.add(first_person_controller.position, fz.mul(3));
```

And don't move your `bulletHolder` around in `draw()`. Remove these lines:

```
bulletHolder.position.x =first_person_controller.position.x;
bulletHolder.position.y =first_person_controller.position.y;
bulletHolder.position.z =first_person_controller.position.z;
```

You'll save yourself a lot of time if you keep each scene graph "holder" object like this at the world coordinate system origin.